# How to make my progress bar animation smoother?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-progressbar

My progress bar is implemented to when the button is pressed down, the progress bar increments. When the button is released, the progress bar resets. The progress bar right now is very glitchy looking. I think it is because it gets called every second and so it jumps like that.

```
        btn.setOnTouchListener{ view, motionEvent ->
            Toast.makeText(context, "Long click detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            var i = 0
            progressBar.progress = i
          val countdownTimer = object: CountDownTimer(5000L, 500L){

               override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                   Log.d(TAG,"button up")
                   Log.d(TAG, "seconds: $p0")
                   if(motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                       i = 0
                       this.cancel()
                   }else{
                       i++
                       progressBar.progress = i*100/(5000/1000)
                   }
               }

               override fun onFinish() {
                   Log.d(TAG, "timer finished")
               }
           }.start()
            true
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to just decrease the time interval for the CountDownTimer so that the progress bar will update more frequently and progress smoother.

```
btn.setOnTouchListener{ view, motionEvent ->
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            progressBar.progress = 0
            if(!isTimerRunning) {
                object : CountDownTimer(5000L, 50L) {

                    override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                        if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            this.cancel()
                        } else {
                            val progress = 100 - ((p0.toFloat() / 5000f) * 100f).toInt()
                            progressBar.progress = progress
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFinish() {
                        progressBar.progress = 100
                        Log.d(TAG, "timer finished")
                    }
                }.start()
            }
            true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the built-in animation utilities to do this. They will let you specify whatever total duration you want, and take care of computing the right "tick" times and rates. You'll get smooth updates without having to do much manual work.

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 0, 100)
animator.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
animator.duration = 5_000 // milliseconds

btn.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            animator.start()
            true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            animator.cancel()
            progressBar.progress = 0
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

This framework will also let you execute code when the progress is finished (or other events, like on animation start):

```
animator.addListener(object: AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
})
```